XPath: How to access information inside xs:appinfo element on an XML Schema
I'm struggling with accessing information inside xs:appinfo element using XPath
I have another well-structured XML inside an xs:appinfo element. Is there a way to directly access a certain element of that XML within the xs:appinfo using XPath? Or is everything within xs:appinfo interpreted as pure text only?
Sample XL Schema:
<xs:schema targetNamespace="ts" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MyElement">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MyChildElement1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="MyChildElement2" type="xs:string">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <AppInfoElement1>Hello</AppInfoElement1>
              <AppInfoElement2>Hello</AppInfoElement2>
            </xs:appinfo>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Any documentation</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>


How can I access the text of AppInfoElement2 inside the appinfo using XPath?
I tried the following:
//xs:annotation/xs:appinfo[.]

//xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/AppInfoElement2[text()]

Actually I run the XPath in an XSLT select statement as follows (I thought this does not make a difference, but none of the proposed answers work for me):
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//*[@name='MyChildElement2']" >
    <xsl:copy-of select="xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/AppInfoElement2/text()" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

I'm using a simple C# application to test this.

While asking an XPath question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath expression that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XPath processor and its conformance with the XPath standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 4.0.

Please try the following XPath: /xs:schema/xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element/xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/AppInfoElement2/text() or //xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/AppInfoElement2/text()

What is the XSLT supposed to output and what does it output? Consider to edit your question and to add those details. If the problem involves writing C# code to run the XSLT you can show that code as well.

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

You need to say what output you want from your XSLT. Do you want to extract just that particular AppInfoElement2? Or do you want a stylesheet whose output is plain text containing the content of that element? Or something else?

I've edited my answer, but I can't suggest a solution until we know what output you actually want.

I also wonder about what you're trying to achieve. Your stylesheet contains a hard-coded XParh query for a particular element MyChildElement2 but it seems unlikely to me that you would always be looking for one particular element definition, so I suspect this is only part of the problem.

It's not really helpful to say that the proposed answers "don't work for me". In what way don't they work? Do they produce errors? Do they return something different from what you want? You need to be a lot clearer and explicit about what you are doing and what result you expect, and why.

This XPath,
//AppInfoElement2/text()

will select all text node children of all AppInfoElement2 elements in the document.
By using //, you bypass the namespaced elements.  Should you ever need to specify namespaced elements in your XPath, see How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?

The issue was indeed because of namespace. The AppInfoElements did not include the "xs:" namespace. Adding this in the XSD or using local-name() in the XSLT solved the issue. Thanks all!

Your second attempt works for me:
//xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/AppInfoElement2[text()]

Result:
<AppInfoElement2 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Hello</AppInfoElement2>

So if it's not working for you then there's something wrong not in the XPath but in the way you are invoking it, i.e. in the host environment in which the XPath expression is evaluated. Perhaps you're not providing the XPath interpreter with a namespace binding for the prefix xs? How you do that is dependent on the host language or platform environment (which you haven't mentioned).
Otherwise, as @kjhughes says, you could just omit the xs:-namespaced elements from your XPath expression:
//AppInfoElement2[text()]

Though this wouldn't be workable if you wanted to distinguish between AppInfoElement2 elements which appeared within different xs:element elements, where you would need a more specific query e.g.:
//xs:element[@name='MyElement']
   //xs:element[@name='MyChildElement2']
      //xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/AppInfoElement2[text()]

EDIT #2:
I'd expect your stylesheet to copy the document but replace this section with the text "hello":
        <xs:element name="MyChildElement2" type="xs:string">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <AppInfoElement1>Hello</AppInfoElement1>
              <AppInfoElement2>Hello</AppInfoElement2>
            </xs:appinfo>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Any documentation</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>

What do you actually want it to do, though?

This is incorrect. The question is how to select the text node inside the AppInfoElement2 element. You are selecting the parent element itself (and only if it has a child text node).

They did in fact ask to "directly access a certain element" so I think my interpretation is quite valid. In any case, if they want to access the child text node of the AppInfoElement2 element it's as simple as adding /text() onto the end of the location path.
